# Why is there a different view among scholars on this topic

Tags: practical-islam, taharah

Salam, I was doing some research and There is a very different opinion about washing clothes in a washing machine. Like if a top got najis and he washed it with other clothes by default it is pure because the amount of water overwhelms the impurity and it washes 2 times and drains itself. Why do scholars still say no to this

Comment: Please share examples of such scholarly views/statements.

Comment: I don’t remember the exact scholars who said this but I was watching a YouTube video from assimalhakeem and he said that it is clean because the water inside the machine is rinsed and drained and it is then topped up cleaning it so it is pure.

Comment: Youtube is a bad teacher! Many scholars say something and in a few days or years say something else. I've heard (and witnessed)  the same sheikh asked about something which he actually answered in some lessons (10-15 years earlier?) of which  tape records are still existing saying something different. And this sheikh is famous and a lot of his videos are spread on youtube. If I watch a video of a scholar 
 then it is rather an explanation of a book this is more safe than "lessons" in which the topic and basis/reference is unknown. Else I prefer to meet and ask him.

Comment: Basically in fiqh water is both pure and purifying. So there's no doubt about this point however most discussions arise from those scholars who consider washing what was touched by the saliva of dogs with soil as essential. Else the matter should be clear.

Comment: I’ll give you an example then, a cloth had sperm on it and it was washed with others in the machine. By default it is clean then is it not because the water is rinsed and washed 2 times. Many scholars agree with this saying but I’m not sure why there’s still some who disagree. I go with the the most common answer most of the times.